# Running ASP.NET code behind on Plesk Scheduled Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, plesk

Just want to ask if by any chance I can schedule an asp net code-behind to run every day at 00:00? What I am doing now is go to Plesk > Scheduled Task > Fetch URL and write the URL on it, hoping the Page Load event of the scheduled page to run. However it seems not to be the case.

I am hosting a website on Hostgator in a sharing environment so Windows Scheduler is not feasible for me, Quartz is as well not feasible as I am an entire beginner for asp.net and still do not know how to exactly use it after googling an hour. Do not even know how to write php so if this is your suggested solution please do make it clear

Any method please do suggest it

If anyone can help that would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance :)

**Another question**

```
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
MySqlDataReader sdr2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
while (sdr2.Read())
{
    string clid = sdr2.GetString(0);
    string couid = sdr2.GetString(0).Split('-')[0] + "-" +b sdr2.GetString(0).Split('-')[1];
    string day = sdr2.GetString(1).ToLower();
    string start = sdr2.GetString(2) + ":00";
    string end = sdr2.GetString(3) + ":00";
    string teacher = sdr2.GetString(4);
    sqlconn.Close();
    sqlconn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand("select " + gra + " from classes where courseid=@cid and " + gra + " is null", sqlconn);
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", couid);
    MySqlDataReader sdr3 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
    if (sdr3.Read())
    {
        sqlconn.Close();
        sqlconn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd5 = new MySqlCommand("delete from enroll where classid = @clid and studentid=@sid;update " + day + " set currentstudent=currentstudent-1 where classid=@clid and start=@start and end=@end and teacher=@teacher", sqlconn);
        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clid", clid);
        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacher", teacher);
        cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This gives an error of connection `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.'` . I think it is because I closed it's original connection of reading sdr2 when opening a new connection for sdr3 and for cmd5. Any way to solve this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, exactly? ASP.net is specifically for generating web content  based on a http request. It can perform some pretty complex server based tasks but it has to be based/intiated by http client request.

Comment: So I want to update the database every day at 00:00, any way to do this? Thanks~

Comment: Are you looking to just update a MySql / MSSQL database everyday at midnight? You can use Plesk Scheduled Tasks to trigger stored procedures against the database rather than trigger c#/vb code to do the same.

Comment: @RazorKillBen- Any more details on how to actually achieve that? Yes you are right, but there are other things I want to do: sending emails based on the field value of a row

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a .net module which can be compiled into a executable you can marshal all your tasks (db calls, email, etc. ) you then need to schedule that module to run at desired time.

Comment: @DaniDev - Thanks for your response. Sadly this is again not possible as Hostgator restricts me to upload any .exe files :/

Comment: OK, then what you will then have to do is code your tasks in server side code (code behind) and then schedule a (windows) task on a client PC to send an HTTP request to the URL of the web App or web API to trigger those tasks.

Comment: you can schedule a Shell script that will start a browser with required URL that triggers your coded server tasks. You just need to make sure that the system that has the scheduled task is on at the time of scheduled request and is configured with the right permissions

Comment: Hi @DaniDev - thank you for your response. I would have a look into this solution, though this requires me to have my computer on during 00:00 every day? 
I am not sure if the problem I am experiencing now is due to different time zone to the server, or because the code behind is not running. I will have a look tomorrow to see if the database is updated or not.

Comment: @DaniDev by the way do you mind to have a look at the question that I just added above ? :)

Comment: @Ken if you like my suggestion/answer to your first question I can post it in the form of an answer and you can accept it. 
2. In regards to your second question, it is separate question and should posted separately. I think you are on to an answer. As yes there is no need to open and close a connection in the middle of a while loop, but there are other issues taht I will be happy to help with if you post as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Code your tasks in server side code (code behind) in your Web Application, and then schedule a (windows) task on a client PC to send an `HTTP` request to the **URL** of your **web App** (or web API) to trigger the **url address** for the code behind that does these tasks.

**`Scheduled Task`**: you can schedule a **(Power) Shell Script** that will start a browser or ([Postman](https://www.postman.com/)) with required URL that triggers your coded server tasks. You just need to make sure that the system that has the scheduled task is on at the time of scheduled request and is configured with the right permissions.